# Javascript Intellisense no longer working for object properties assigned after initial object creation in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: javascript, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, visual-studio-2022

In VS2022 there seems to have been some major revision in the Javascript Intellisense Service in comparison to VS2019.

Javascript Intellisense no longer seems to recognize object properties assigned outside of the initial creation context.

```
var r = { a: 1, b: 2 };
r.c = 3;
//"r.a" and "r.b" will here be identified by Intellisense, but not "r.c".
```

This is some highly frustrating behaviour when there are scopes and dependency injected objects like in an AngularJs project since these no longer offer intellisense autocomplete or navigation using "go to definition".

This has previously worked very well **without** JSDoc headers in VS2019.

###### Visual Studio 2019

`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e` are all available here.

[image: Intellisense correctly working in VS2019]

###### Visual Studio 2022

Only `a`,`b`,`d` are available here.

[image: VS2022 no longer recognizes properties assigned outside of the creation context]

Is there any known setting or package to alter/correct this new behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in javascript you don't have type declarations and since you're delaring just two properties it supposes taht your object contains only those.
You can avoid this by adding comments, no changes in the code/logic but intellisense will recognize them

```js
/** @type { {a: number, b: number, c?: number} } */
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// Now you can access every property your object has (not only the declared) and intellisense will recognize those declared
```

[image]

In the same way you can declare:

```js
/** @type {string} */
const num = 12;

// Now intellisense will recognize it as a string even if it's a number
// and because in JS it's not an error to assign a number or a string to
// a variable it will throw an error at runtime if you try thing like
// num.trim();
```

Make sure of what you're declaring

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main issue here is that my example has previously worked in VS2019 without the JsDoc headers.
The project i'm currently working in is a major AngularJs project and the JsDoc headers won't be passed along when the objects are dependency injected. So an injected Factory or Controller will no longer be recognized as an instance of said Object in VS. Adding JsDoc headers to every part of the entire project is not a viable option anyway due to the sheer magnitude of the task.

Comment: Ok i misunderstood your question, also in angular you use typescript so you won't need the comments. That's strange, i don't know what it could be. I'm upvoting your question so others can see it

Comment: No worries. It is very good practice to use JSDoc and should be used where ever applicable. Though in this very instance it's not really realistic to implement. I also want to point out that Angular and AngularJs are two completely different frameworks. AngularJs does not make use TypeScript but Angular does, just as you stated. AngularJs is actually Angular 1.0 and can be seen as a precursor to Angular 2+. There are several major differences in how they both work since Angular 2 was a complete rework of the entire concept.